# Solaris : TOP command, RES mem not coing down ( java program )

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory, memory-management, solaris

I am running load through my java program and analyzing memory consumption through jconsole and top command.

"uname -a" machine on which i am working is  :

SunOS 5.10 Generic_142909-17 sun4v sparc sun4v

My issue is that if i see memory consumption through top command then RES mem increases when load is running,which is fine but it does not come down when i stop the load.

If GC occurs then also RES mem does not come down.Opposite to that in Jconsole, I can see that mem consumption comes down when GC occurs.

TOP OUTPUT :

PID USERNAME LWP PRI NICE  SIZE   **RES** STATE    TIME    CPU COMMAND
 16959 aconyx   836  59    0 7559M **3696M** sleep   61:27  0.04% java

JConsole Output :

[image]

At same point in time jconsole showing 384 MB used and top RES showing 3696 MB used.

Any pointers why top RES memory does not come down like visible in jconsole.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The importat bit to know is that the java GC doesn't free the memory to the OS, it just frees it so it can be reused by the JVM.

Comment: Ok.So this means that top always shows the highest memory which my program has used and it is independent from java GC.This means that above behavior from top command is acceptable...

Comment: Exactly!! This might not happen with other applications (in C, C++), but it's the way it works with java.

Comment: It happens with most applications on Solaris - the `free()` function in C and `delete` in C++ just return memory to the application heap, applications have to make a special effort to reduce the heap size and return memory to the OS.